# in vue-cli vuex , use this.$store can't get store object, but use this.$store.store it works

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

[that this.$store.state I get a undefined, but use this.$store.store get a correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMm3Y.png)

[store/index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaWmP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by that `export default`. Try to export directly the const.

Example:

**`store.js`**

```
import 'Vue' from 'vue';
import 'Vuex' from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
     //your code here//
  }
});
```

**`Main.js`**

```
import 'store' from 'wherever the file is/mystore.js';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store, <-- Here is defined store to use along the my app
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Comment: it works，I'm very thank you for you help, it solves my puzzle for a few days, but I still have perplexed for when i use `export default` it will make mistakes， if use must use `export default` then how to write it

Comment: get it, if I use ```export { store }```, it will be fine, I should to read es6 modules carefully, thanks you again for give me a direction,